# Can Entity Framework do what Linq To SQL does?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I'm a bit confused, I have worked with Linq To SQL and gather we can query anything in the dbml or entities e.g:

```
var query = from i in db.mytable
            select i;
```

But in the Entity Framework (which supposedly Microsoft are replacing Linq To SQL with) how can we do the same thing? Is it even possible? How does it replace Linq To SQL?

Would be grateful of any examples of the Entity Framework - i.e how the above is done in the Entity Framework! Thanks.

Comment: Entity Framework, is not as of yet a complete replacement for L2S. EF still has lot's of linq operators not implemented.

Comment: Yes, that query will work. But as soon as your query goes even slightly more complex you will notice some major differences; inefficient and overly complex SQL queries generated by EF, and as Pop Catalin mentioned above - a whole heap of operators are not implemented/supported in L2E or are translated to less-than-optimal SQL. Things like 'LIKE' comparisons, left joins, various math functions (e.g. Round()) works fine with L2S but will throw a runtime error when used with L2E.

Comment: @KristoferA Thanks for the valuable information . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing only you want to write

```
var query = from i in db.mytable
            select i;
```

i think you are not created the object(db) properly for Entity Framework

[LINQ To SQL Vs. Entity Framework](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/04/20/linq-to-sql-vs-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: how does it know what database you are saving to then?

Answer (score 3):

Yes more or less the same - you have [Linq-to-Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx), which should definitely support that simple LINQ query.

Entity Framework is much more than just a "bloated" Linq-to-SQL - see some [points here](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/linq-to-sql-vs-entity-framework/).

This [article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1237071) shows quite nicely how to write Linq-to-Entities queries in your code.

Linq-to-Entities does not support the full Linq-to-SQL set of functionality for now, but EF4 (with .NET 4.0) is around the corner (should be released before the end of 2009, says Microsoft) and will bring massively more functionality and goodness to the EF space! Stay tuned.

Marc

Comment: The *points here* link to Julie Lerman's blog is broken, it has a trailing '$'. Use [this](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/linq-to-sql-vs-entity-framework/)

Comment: @FelipeRomero: sorry 'bout that - I fixed the URL, link should work again. Enjoy!